# Clang error after switching to XCode 5

Tags: clang, xcode5, core-plot

After having updated to XCode 5 i am getting the follwoing error on compile in the CorePlot Library:

> clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

I tried changing the build setting to match a working example project from the lib with no success..

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? Release 1.4 and later is compatible with Xcode 5.

Comment: changing to 1.4 resolved my problems. thanks.